# Extract upper or lower triangular part of a numpy matrix

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning

I have a matrix `A` and I want 2 matrices `U` and `L` such that `U` contains the upper triangular elements of A (all elements above and not including diagonal) and similarly for `L`(all elements below and not including diagonal). Is there a `numpy` method to do this?

e.g

```
A = array([[ 4.,  9., -3.],
           [ 2.,  4., -2.],
           [-2., -3.,  7.]])

U = array([[ 0.,  9., -3.],
           [ 0.,  0., -2.],
           [ 0.,  0.,  0.]])

L = array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
           [ 2.,  0.,  0.],
           [-2., -3.,  0.]])
```

Answer (score 105, accepted):

Try [`numpy.triu`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.triu.html) (triangle-upper) and [`numpy.tril`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tril.html) (triangle-lower).

Code example:

```
np.triu([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[10,11,12]])
array([[ 1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6],
       [ 0,  8,  9],
       [ 0,  0, 12]])
```

Comment: To the OP: It's often useful to know that they take a `k` argument, too, for which diagonal to extract above or below (which can be _really_ useful when you need it!).  Additionally, there are the functions `np.triu_indices`, `np.tril_indices`, `np.triu_indices_from`, and `np.tril_indices_from` to generate indices to index the upper or lower triangle with.  (The "from" versions just take an input array instead of a shape)

Answer (score 124):

To **extract the upper triangle values** to a flat vector,
you can do something like the following:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
print(a)

#array([[1, 2, 3],
#       [4, 5, 6],
#       [7, 8, 9]])

a[np.triu_indices(3)]
#or
list(a[np.triu_indices(3)])

#array([1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 9])
```

---

Similarly, for the **lower triangle**, use `np.tril`.

---

### *IMPORTANT*

If you want to extract the values that are **above the diagonal** (or **below**) then use the **k** argument. This is usually used when the matrix is symmetric.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])

#array([[1, 2, 3],
#       [4, 5, 6],
#       [7, 8, 9]])

a[np.triu_indices(3, k = 1)]

# this returns the following
array([2, 3, 6])
```

---

### **EDIT (on 11.11.2019):**

To put back the extracted vector into a 2D symmetric array, one can follow my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58806626/5025009

Comment: You can also use `np.triu_indices_from(a)`, so you don't need to manually specify the size of the matrix.

Answer (score 22):

Use the [Array Creation Routines](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/routines.array-creation.html#building-matrices) of [numpy.triu](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.triu.html#numpy.triu) and [numpy.tril](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.triu.html#numpy.tril) to return a copy of a matrix with the elements above or below the k-th diagonal zeroed.

```
    >>> a = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
    >>> a
    array([[1, 2, 3],
           [4, 5, 6],
           [7, 8, 9]])

    >>> tri_upper_diag = np.triu(a, k=0)
    >>> tri_upper_diag
    array([[1, 2, 3],
           [0, 5, 6],
           [0, 0, 9]])

    >>> tri_upper_no_diag = np.triu(a, k=1)
    >>> tri_upper_no_diag
    array([[0, 2, 3],
           [0, 0, 6],
           [0, 0, 0]])

    >>> tri_lower_diag = np.tril(a, k=0)
    >>> tri_lower_diag
    array([[1, 0, 0],
           [4, 5, 0],
           [7, 8, 9]])

    >>> tri_lower_no_diag = np.tril(a, k=-1)
    >>> tri_lower_no_diag
    array([[0, 0, 0],
           [4, 0, 0],
           [7, 8, 0]])
```

Comment: How would you fill with something else than `0`, line `np.inf` for example?