# how to copy only upper triangular values into array from numpy.triu()?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a square matrix A (could be any size) and I want to take the upper triangular part and place those values in an array without the values below the center diagonal (k=0).

```
A = array([[ 4,  0,  3],
           [ 2,  4, -2],
           [-2, -3,  7]])
```

using numpy.triu(A) gets me to

```
A = array([[ 4,  0,  3],
           [ 0,  4, -2],
           [ 0,  0,  7]])
```

but from here how would I copy only the upper triangular elements into a simply array? Such as:

```
[4, 0, 3, 4, -2, 7]
```

I was going to just iterate though and copy all non-zero elements, however zero's in the upper triangular are allowed.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use Numpy's [upper triangular indices function](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.triu_indices.html) to extract the upper triangular of `A` into a flat array:

```
>>> A[np.triu_indices(3)]
array([ 4,  0,  3,  4, -2,  7])
```

And can easily convert this to a Python list:

```
>>> list(A[np.triu_indices(3)])
[4, 0, 3, 4, -2, 7]
```

Answer (score 6):

[transform the upper/lower triangular part of a symmetric matrix (2D array) into a 1D array and return it to the 2D format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17527693/transform-the-upper-lower-triangular-part-of-a-symmetric-matrix-2d-array-into?lq=1)

```
indices = np.triu_indices_from(A)
A = np.asarray( A[indices] )
```