# numpy merge upper and lower triangular

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I essentially would like to do the opposite of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8905501/extract-upper-lower-triangular-part-of-a-numpy-matrix). I have two matrixes that have been split with `np.tril` or `np.triu` and I want to recombine them into a single matrix.

```
A = array([[ 0. ,  0. ,  0. ],
           [ 0.1,  0. ,  0. ],
           [ 0.6,  0.5,  0. ]])

B = array([[ 0. ,  0.4,  0.8],
           [ 0. ,  0. ,  0.3],
           [ 0. ,  0. ,  0. ]])
```

And what I want it to look like is

```
array([[ 0. ,  0.4,  0.8],
       [ 0.1,  0. ,  0.3],
       [ 0.6,  0.5,  0. ]])
```

Is there an inbuilt numpy function to do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You mean `A+B` ?

```
import numpy
A = numpy.array([[ 0. ,  0. ,  0. ],
           [ 0.1,  0. ,  0. ],
           [ 0.6,  0.5,  0. ]])

B = numpy.array([[ 0. ,  0.4,  0.8],
           [ 0. ,  0. ,  0.3],
           [ 0. ,  0. ,  0. ]])

print A+B
```

returns

```
array([[ 0. ,  0.4,  0.8],
       [ 0.1,  0. ,  0.3],
       [ 0.6,  0.5,  0. ]])
```

Answer (score 1):

If the values are strings, then this works as long as B is the upper triangle.

```
A = np.array([[ 0. ,  0. ,  0. ],
           [ '0.1**',  0. ,  0. ],
           [ 0.6,  '0.5**',  0. ]])

B = np.array([[ 0. ,  0.4,  '0.8***'],
           [ 0. ,  0. ,  0.3],
           [ 0. ,  0. ,  0. ]])

for i in range(0,len(A)):
    for j in range(0,i):
        B[i,j]=A[i,j]
            
B
```

Returns

```
array([['0.0', '0.4', '0.8***'],
       ['0.1**', '0.0', '0.3'],
       ['0.6', '0.5**', '0.0']], dtype='<U32')
```