# How to get all the diagonal two-dimensional list without using numpy?

Tags: python, list

We have:
`a = [[1, 2, 4], [-1, 3, 4], [9, -3, 7]]`

Diagonal traversal as a list:
`[1, -1, 2, 9, 3, 4]`

```
n = int(input())
a = [[0]*n for _ in range(n)]
for i in range(n):
    a[i] = [int(j) for j in input().strip().split(" ")]

res = []
for j in range(n):
    for k in range(j + 1):
        res.append(a[j - k][k])
print(res)
```

How do I get the remaining two diagonals?
I need to get:
`[-3, 4, 7]`

Comment: The main diagonal of a 3x3 matrix has 3 elements. The side diagonals have less elements. Your example has 6 elements. Why?

Comment: In your example, the diagonal is [1, 3, 7].

Comment: @MartinThoma My example contains a list in which the first three diagonals.

Comment: @MartinThoma this is a side diagonal

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8905501/extract-upper-or-lower-triangular-part-of-a-numpy-matrix

Comment: This is not diagonal, but it is diagonal traversal, or zigzag traversal, please edit the question!

Comment: @MartinThoma  diagonal traversal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. Define variables COL and ROW and then run the following function with your matrix.

```
def diagonalOrder(matrix) :       
    # There will be ROW+COL-1 lines in the output   
    for line in range(1, (ROW + COL)) :   
        # Get column index of the first element  
        # in this line of output. The index is 0   
        # for first ROW lines and line - ROW for   
        # remaining lines    
        start_col = max(0, line - ROW) 

        # Get count of elements in this line. 
        # The count of elements is equal to  
        # minimum of line number, COL-start_col and ROW     
        count = min(line, (COL - start_col), ROW) 

        # Print elements of this line     
        for j in range(0, count) :   
            print(matrix[min(ROW, line) - j - 1]   
                        [start_col + j], end = "\t")   
        print()
```

Answer (score 1):

First, see this 3x3 matrix with each element containing its row in the first digit and its column in the second digit.

```
00  01  02
10  11  12
20  21  22
```

The elements that you want are in the order:

```
00  10  01  20  11  02  21  12  22
```

Or in other perspective:

```
00
10 01
20 11 02
21 12
22
```

You can see that, in the first column of the numbers above, the first digits are `01222`. This represents `range(3) + [2, 2]`. Now, look at the second digits of the first column. They are `00012` and represents `[0, 0] + range(3)`.

Also, note that, in each row, each element decreases its first digit and increases its second digit until the element is equal to its inverse. You can see it more clearly in the third row. It starts at `20`, goes to `11` and stop at `02`, which is the inverse of `20`, the initial number.

So, you can do something like:

```
def toNumber(i, j):
    return int(str(i) + str(j))

res = []
a = [[1, 2, 3],
     [4, 5, 6],
     [7, 8, 9]]

list1 = list(range(3)) + [2]*2
list2 = [0]*2 + list(range(3))

for i, j in zip(list1, list2):
    inverse = int(str(toNumber(i, j))[::-1])
    while True:
        res.append(a[i][j])
        if toNumber(i, j) == inverse:
            break
        i -= 1
        j += 1

print(res)
```