# Transform Matrix to Vector in specific order

Tags: python, matrix, numpy-ndarray

A couple of questions have discussed how to transform a matrix/table to an array/vector (see for instance here: [Extract upper or lower triangular part of a numpy matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8905501/extract-upper-or-lower-triangular-part-of-a-numpy-matrix))

But I would like to do this a very specific order, like so (matrix is symmetric):

```
m = np.matrix([[11, 21, 31],
               [21, 22, 32],
               [31, 32, 33]])
```

target output:

```
#array([11, 21, 22, 31, 32, 33])
```

Comment: `m[np.triu_indices(m.shape[0])]`

Comment: Perfect, thank you.