# How to make create a triangle of "1"?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to create this from multiple arrays, best using NumPy:

```
1 0 0 0 0 0
1 1 0 0 0 0
1 1 1 0 0 0
1 1 1 1 0 0
1 1 1 1 1 0
1 1 1 1 1 1
```

However, I prefer if a library is used to create this, how do I go about doing this?

Note: NumPy can be used to create the array as well.

There are a lot of answers on SO, but they all provide answers that *do not* use libraries, and I haven't been able to find anything online to produce this!

Comment: `np.triu` and `np.tril` .

Comment: Why do you need to use library?

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych Just curious how they may help out, I prefer to use them

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extract upper or lower triangular part of a numpy matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8905501/extract-upper-or-lower-triangular-part-of-a-numpy-matrix)

Comment: No @Murali, my question is different and does not "extract"

Comment: @DialFrost Well, you create an array with all ones and "extract" the lower triangular matrix. That is exactly what the proposed answers are doing.

Comment: @Murali Mine is different, I was mainly looking at and pointing out `numpy.tri`, something that the question you provided does not point out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Using [`numpy.tri`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.tri.html)

Syntax:

```
numpy.tri(N, M=None, k=0, dtype=<class 'float'>, *, like=None)
```

Basically it creates an array with `1`'s at and below the given diagonal and `0`'s elsewhere.

Example:

```
import numpy as np
np.tri(6, dtype=int)

>>>
array([[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`np.tril`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.tril.html):

```py
>>> np.tril(np.ones((6, 6), dtype=int))
array([[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]])
```